# spinning a 2d Cube

Tags: 2d, 3d, rendering

I know that a cube is actually a 3d shape , but i have some other problem over here.

I have been doing 2D Game dev using libgdx but have never touched 3D rendering. Now what I want in my 2D game is that instead of coins I make my player collect magical cubes. But those cubes need to be spinning on one Diagonal, same can be seen in popular game Vector.

[Here is a screenshot](http://www.pocketplayers.info/Joomla/images/android_spiele_berichte_android_games_reviews/vector_game_android_07.jpg).

Can someone explaing the mathematics of such an animation

Comment: I believe those are just animated sprites. easy to do those renders in any model render today.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create an actual 3D object within your game to achieve that.

Simply make an animation of a cube rotating and render that. It's simple! LibGDX has a [short tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation) written about it.